# Android : How to really move controls by code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Recently I am doing a project with a function that an `ImageView` can move with my fingers and at the same time it can change the `Image src` of the `ImageView`.
I use the Layout function of the ImageView and `setImageBitmap` function to change the `ImageView`'s `Bitmap` src.
But when the function `setImageBitmap` ends, my `ImageView` returned to the original place in the `layout.xml`.
I guess it is because that the `setImageBitmap` provokes the function `Invalidate` and then it moves to the original place.So maybe the control is not really moved.
How can I really move the control or set the `Bitmap` src without let my control go back to the original place ?

Comment: in your set bitmap dont hardcode the x,y position add it as dynamic values and update it with touch possition reffer any gaming tutorials in android to get a detailed review

Comment: Can you give me a tutorial website? I dont know which one may contain this infomation. Thx

Comment: hm hope this has it http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-basic-game_05.html i am not sure but

Comment: Do you mean use the SurfaceView? But actually, I am using the surface view... But the surface view cannot act an animation... I think I may find some other way to work it out..